# Spring Boot Data Redis - Serialize to json -> class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I'm using `Spring Boot 2.4.2` with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In my appication I have

```
package com.tuto.app1;
import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
}
```

Also

```
@Bean
public CacheManager redisCacheManager() {
    RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair<Object> jsonSerializer =
            RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class));
    return RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder
            .fromConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory())
            .cacheDefaults(
                    RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                            .entryTtl(Duration.ofDays(1))
                            .serializeValuesWith(jsonSerializer)
            )
            .build();
}
```

And

```
@GetMapping("/students/{name}")
@Cacheable(value = "student")
public Student getStudent(@PathVariable String name) {
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setFirstName("John");
    student.setLastName(name);
    student.setAge(30);
    return student;
}
```

First call to `http://.../app1/students/toto` returns

```
{
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "toto",
"age": 30
}
```

And in cache I have

```
{"firstName":"John","lastName":"toto","age":30}
```

Ok, it's what I want.

BUT ... all other call to `http://.../app1/students/toto`are giving me

```
class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.tuto.app1.Student (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.tuto.app1.Student is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @32bd421)
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.tuto.app1.Student (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.tuto.app1.Student is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @32bd421)
```

What would be the solution ?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875635/storing-raw-json-in-redis-by-using-spring-data-redis)

Comment: It's what I'm doing except that it uses GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.  Doing so the cahe well contains {"@class":"com.tuto.app1.Student","firstName":"John","lastName":"toto","age":30}.  Ok, it is woking.  Even for the 2nd call.  But it's not what I want.  I want to keep json without the class name.

Answer (score 0):

you can set json string data for redis.
for example:

```
redistemplate.opsxxx.set("key",JSON.toJsonString(new JavaBean()));
String json = redistemplate.opsxxx.get("key");
//convert
JSON.parseObject(json,JavaBean.class);
```