# how can i store redis value not address in class

Tags: java, redis

i am using redis Repository

```
@RedisHash
@Data
@Builder

public class CustomClass<String,T> {
     @Id
     String id;
     T data;
}
```

when i saved data using crud Repository

i found that there is a class name not data values in Redis store
like this

```
 data   class com.sec.common.tmp.CustomClass
```

how can i store T class data as Json Type ?

```
data {id: "Test", name : "test" }
```

Comment: `com.sec.common.tmp.CustomClass` is not an address but a class name. That result could  come from not serializing the data properly which might be caused due to the type being  a generic type. This means the (fully qualified) class name would need to be included in the serialized value in order to deserialize it into the same type again. Please show how you're writing and reading the data from Redis, ideally share a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [storing raw json in redis by using spring-data-redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875635/storing-raw-json-in-redis-by-using-spring-data-redis)